# Creating install files from older versions of Mathematica for MacOS

Tags: mac-os-x, installation

I bought a new Mac and would like to install previous versions of *Mathematica* on it.  Unfortunately, I lost my USB containing all the `.dmg` files of previous versions of *Mathematica* for Mac OS.  But, I still have them all installed on my older mac in the standard Applications directory.  Is it possible to use these installed version to somehow recreate the dmg files, so that I may install them on my new computer?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to recreate any DMG files.  The DMG files are simply a means to store `Mathematica.app`, just like a zip file.  You can simply zip up (compress) `Mathematica.app` on your old computer, transfer to the new one, then uncompress.  This assumes that you made no modifications to Mathematica's `$InstallationDirectory` on your old computer (i.e. you did not right-click Mathematica.app, choose Show Package Contents, then modify the contents).

This works because most Mac apps do not need any installation at all.  Applications are *usually* self-contained, and can be copied around freely.